# Initializing an `atomic_int` with a braced constant: Is this valid C code? If so why does it not compile in clang?

Tags: gcc, clang, c11

I'm porting some code from C11 to C++. The project compiles fine in `gcc` and `g++` but `clang` refuses to compile it. The offending lines are shown below:

```
static atomic_int sem = {0};
```

> src/testdir.c:27:25: error: illegal initializer type 'atomic_int'
>         (aka '_Atomic(int)')

and

```
struct container {
    volatile atomic_ullong workerThreadCount;
    struct cfgoptions *config;
    repaircmd_t *cmd;
};
Container container = {{0}, s, NULL};
```

> src/testdir.c:334:25: error: illegal initializer type 'volatile atomic_ullong'
>         (aka 'volatile _Atomic(unsigned long long)')

Clang:
clang version 3.7.0 (tags/RELEASE_370/final)

gcc:
gcc (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)

Operating system:
Fedora 23

Test code:
https://gist.github.com/clockley/eb42964003a2e4fe6de97d5b192d61d3

P.S i = {0} or i(0) are the only valid initializers in C++ as atomic ints are not primitive types of the two only the former is valid C.

Comment: b/c int i ={ 0} is valid c code

Comment: Do you see what the compiler message says there? The syntax itself is fine. What's not fine is what appears to be a typedef in both cases. It looks like a missing header.

Comment: The header for C11 is included.

Comment: Could also be a redefined typedef. Look up how `atomic_int` and `atomic_ullong` are defined for `C11` vs `C++`.

Comment: Have you try with `{}` (so `static atomic_int sem = 0;`)?

Comment: It might be relevant to document which versions of GCC/G++ and Clang you are using, and the platform on which you're using them.  It would definitely be worth creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) and showing the full error messages.  The MCVE might be as simple as the code shown plus `#include <stdatomics.h>`.

Comment: Changed code to volatile _Atomic(unsigned long long) which should fix a typedef problem. same error message: src/testdir.c:334:25: error: illegal initializer type 'volatile _Atomic(unsigned
      long long)'

Comment: Update the question with the extra information — don't add it to the comments, and do not destroy the question.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/clockley/eb42964003a2e4fe6de97d5b192d61d3

Comment: clang:3.7.0 gcc:(GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6 OS:fedora 23

Comment: Please — add the extra information to the question, not in the comments.  Thank you!

Comment: "*The header for C11 is included.*" -- Which header? If a header is `#include`d, you need to show it in the source code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in clang.

Here's a simple test case, with the result of compiling it with gcc and clang:

```
$ cat c.c
static _Atomic int x = ( 42 );
static _Atomic int y = { 42 };
$ gcc-6.1.0 -std=c11 -c c.c
$ clang-3.7 -std=c11 -c c.c
c.c:2:24: error: illegal initializer type '_Atomic(int)'
static _Atomic int y = { 42 };
                       ^
1 error generated.
$
```

C explicitly permits the initializer for a scalar object to be enclosed in braces ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9p11). I see nothing that forbids such an initializer for an atomic object.

Atomics are an optional feature in C11, but both gcc and clang support it (neither predefines `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__`).

As a workaround, I suggest just dropping the braces.  This:

```
static _Atomic int z = 42;
```

is valid and accepted by both compilers.

If you're need the code to compile both as C and as C++, then you might want to reconsider that requirement. But if it's really necessary, you can use the `__cplusplus` predefined macro to distinguish between C and C++ compilers:

```
static _Atomic int foo = 
#ifdef __cplusplus
    { 42 };
#else
    42;
#endif
```

or play some other tricks with macros.

(I'll note that C11's `<stdatomic.h>` header defines a macro `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` that's intended to be used to initialize atomic objects, with an example:

```
atomic_int guide = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(42);
```

It appears to be needed for atomic objects with automatic storage duration, which doesn't apply here.)

Comment: Thank's I'll report the bug next week.

Comment: __Atomic = C only, std::atomic<int> = C++ only, atomic_int = C/C++

Comment: No, I think clang is right the C standard says: *An atomic object
with automatic storage duration that is not explicitly initialized using
`ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` is initially in an indeterminate state;*

Comment: @JensGustedt: The object is static, not automatic. Even if that weren't the case, it wouldn't explain the fatal "illegal initializer type" error. But that doesn't explain the need for `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT`, at least for automatic objects.

Comment: @KeithThompson, if a platform realy needs to have something different for `_ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(X)` than `{ X }` depends on the implementation. Atomics are e.g allowed to be some sort of structure that has a lock field or whatever, completely up to the implementation. So the precaution is that implementors can hide any magic they want inside this macro. To have a unified approach this is requested for *all* atomic types, and to be portable an application should always use this. For C++ the implementation  can hide such magic in a constructor definition.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Sorry, that was a horrible typo. I meant to write that it *does* explain the need for `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT`, at least for automatic objects.

Answer (score -3):

I must disagree strongly with *Mad Physicist*.  The braces **{}** are used to initialize an aggregate.  A single int is not an aggregate.  You may put the initializer in **()** if you like, but **{}** are **verboten**.  It would be an aggregate if you dimensioned it out to one entry, as in:

**static atomic_int  sem[ 1 ] = { 0 };**

or even

**static atomic_int  sem[] = { 0 };**

if you're too lazy to count one integer initializer!

Comment: I couldn't get GCC or Clang to agree with you in C11 mode, even with `-pedantic`. I went to look at the C11 standard, and §6.7 Declarations says: _init-declarator:
declarator |
declarator = initializer_, and §6.7.9 Initialization says: _initializer:
assignment-expression | 
`{` initializer-list `}` |
`{` initializer-list , `}`_ and there isn't a rule about "only use `{` … `}` with aggregates" so it appears to be legitimate in C11, and in C99 too. I was a bit surprised. (§6.7.9 ¶11 explicitly says: _The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces._)

Comment: Incorrect. Braces are permitted. Quoting [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9p11: "The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces."